# Variable is undefined for some purposes, defined for others

Tags: javascript, variables, console

I was wanting to look at the format of NewEgg's product IDs, so from their homepage I tried to run the following script to spit out the ID of all linked products to the console:

```
for (var i=0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
    if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("Product.aspx")!=-1) {
        var itemNo=document.links[i].href.split("Item=")[1];
        console.log(itemNo);
    }
}
```

(As you can see, product links have "Product.aspx" in them, followed by `?Item=[itemid]`. Simple `split` to get the part after `?Item=`). This script worked fine. However, when I tried to get "fancier", I started getting error messages that `itemNo` was undefined. Here's the script I tried:

```
for (var i=0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
    if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("Product.aspx")!=-1) {
        var itemNo=document.links[i].href.split("Item=")[1];'
        if (itemNo.charAt(0)=="N") {//look at only IDs that start with 'N'
            console.log(itemNo);
        }
    }
}
```

This reported that itemNo was undefined in the second `if` statement (inner `if` on the fourth line above). Commenting out the `if` statement (lines 4 and 6) made it work fine again. So basically, I can log it, but I can't `if` it. I also tried some more string manipulation in place of the `if` before logging, but after the line that defines `itemNo`, I can't do much except log it. I tried changing the variable name to no avail.

Admittedly, this is from the Firebug console (also tried Firefox's native Scratchpad), so the environment is a bit different, but I see no reason why the variable should be defined sometimes, but undefined other times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your search criteria.

As you can see some links have "Product.aspx" but aren't links for a product, like this one:
"http://www.newegg.com/Store/NewProduct.aspx?Name=What%27s-New"

You should be more specific like:

```
for (var i=0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
    if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("/Product.aspx?")!=-1) {
        // Added log
        console.log(document.links[i].href);

        var itemNo=document.links[i].href.split("Item=")[1];
        if (itemNo.charAt(0)=="N") {
            console.log(itemNo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not a problem with Firebug at all. If you try the following:

```
for (var i=0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
    if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("Product.aspx")!=-1) {
        // Added log
        console.log(document.links[i].href);

        var itemNo=document.links[i].href.split("Item=")[1];
        if (itemNo.charAt(0)=="N") {
            console.log(itemNo);
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice that the very first link does *not* have `Item=` in the querystring. Thus, when you try to split the href, you get back `undefined`, and then try to run `charAt()`, which of course throws a TypeError.

Basically, you just weren't checking for `undefined`. A simple check should do it:

```
for (var i=0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
    if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("Product.aspx")!=-1) {
        var itemNo=document.links[i].href.split("Item=")[1];
        // Right here
        if (itemNo && itemNo.charAt(0)=="N") {
            console.log(itemNo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the very first result of your first script (which works fine). It is undefined. That is the reason of the error in your second script.

You should rewrite it checking if itemNo is underfined:

```
for (var i=0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("Product.aspx")!=-1) {
    var itemNo=document.links[i].href.split("Item=")[1];
    if (itemNo!=undefined&&itemNo.charAt(0)=="N") {//look at only product ideas that start with N
        console.log(itemNo);
    }
}
```

}